# Are there any Red Wizards among the mercenaries at the Well of the Dragons?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, rise-of-tiamat

In the adventure module *Rise of Tiamat*, one of the conflicts involves:

> The Red Wizards of Thay

These characters are tantamount to one of the evil plots, so I'm trying to account for them all since my players may decide to attempt to assassinate them. In one section it is detailed:

> "All of the Red Wizards are presently in the Temple of Tiamat." (20,21 on page 83). This seems to refer to the 9 generic Red Wizards and Rath Modal.

...but then in another section (seemingly contradicting the prior):

> Red Wizards not performing the ritual are embedded with mercenary units and troops of armed cultists to provide extra firepower. (**Red Wizards** on page 86)

How many of these characters satisfy the latter case, if any? Is there some different meaning behind these two passages that I'm missing?

Comment: Putting red wizards in the spoiler block when they are already in the title makes little sense. If anything, hiding module would help bit more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There doesn't seem to be a contradiction

The section 20,21 in page 83 states (emphasis mine):

> The Red Wizards whose magic raises the Temple of Tiamat in the caldera **and who will perform the ritual that draws the Dragon Queen into the world** are housed in these two caverns. [...]  All the Red Wizards are presently in the Temple of Tiamat.

To me, this clearly refers to the same group of red wizards. Contrasting this passage with the one you already quote...

> Red Wizards not performing the ritual are embedded with mercenary units and troops of armed cultists to provide extra firepower.

...simply suggests that these others are probably...

> housed somewhere else and not part of the special group of 9 participating in the ritual. Their exact location and numbers are never explicitly stated as far as I could tell but they are possibly among the other allies of the cult mentioned at the start of the chapter in p. 79: "The thousands of mercenaries, giants, devils, and monsters serving the cult are camped chiefly along the north and east slopes."

Comment: That's not on you. That chapter is poorly written, as it is.